# linux + lsblk command

Tags: linux, boot, partition, raid

from my linux redhat machine we run lsblk
and we get the following:

```
  lsblk
  NAME               MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINT
  sda                  8:0    0  14.6T  0 disk
  sdb                  8:16   0 372.6G  0 disk
  ├─sdb1               8:17   0   512M  0 part
  │ └─md0              9:0    0   512M  0 raid1 /boot
  └─sdb2               8:18   0 372.1G  0 part
  └─md1              9:1    0   372G  0 raid1
  ├─vg00-lv_root 253:0    0    50G  0 lvm   /
   ├─vg00-lv_swap 253:1    0    16G  0 lvm   [SWAP]
   └─vg00-lv_var  253:2    0    30G  0 lvm   /var
    sdc                  8:32   0 372.6G  0 disk
 ├─sdc1               8:33   0   512M  0 part
 │     └─md0              9:0    0   512M  0 raid1 /boot
 └─sdc2               8:34   0 372.1G  0 part
 └─md1              9:1    0   372G  0 raid1
   ├─vg00-lv_root 253:0    0    50G  0 lvm   /
   ├─vg00-lv_swap 253:1    0    16G  0 lvm   [SWAP]
   └─vg00-lv_var  253:2    0    30G  0 lvm   /var
```

what inst reasonable is why we get two duplicate partitions here , as /boot ?
is that mean we need to push out the second disk as sdc?

my disk's in the HW:

```
sfdisk -s
/dev/sda: 15623782400
/dev/sdb: 390711384
/dev/md1: 390054912
/dev/md0:    524224
/dev/sdc: 390711384



cat /proc/mdstat
Personalities : [raid1]
md0 : active raid1 sdc1[1] sdb1[0]
     524224 blocks super 1.0 [2/2] [UU]
     bitmap: 0/1 pages [0KB], 65536KB chunk

md1 : active raid1 sdc2[1] sdb2[0]
      390054912 blocks super 1.2 [2/2] [UU]
      bitmap: 0/3 pages [0KB], 65536KB chunk
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing is that `lsblk` doesn't list *partitions*, it lists block *devices*.

You're seeing `/boot` twice, but that's referring to the `/boot` *mount point*, which is mounted from a RAID1 *multiple device (md)* block device composed of two partitions: sdc1 and sdb1.

Since disks, partitions, and *multiple device* are all block devices, you're bound to see duplication in the mount points.

Comment: so what is he conclusion - this is raid 1 mirror between two disk , or if not we can use one disk only ( push out the sec disk ? )

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by pushing out the sec disk. but you do have a raid 1 mirror using two disks, and your /boot filesystem is on that mirror.

Comment: for testing - we can push  the primary  disk and the second disk will be active , or vice versa ( we can push out the second disk and the first disk will be active

Comment: Ah, yes, that's true. Being RAID1, each disk has a complete copy of the filesystem. So you can run with just one of the disks. It not just /boot that's affected though, your LVM logical volumes are also on a RAID1 using the same two disks. I hope you test this out on a non-production server :)